# typescript: шаблонная функция в которой в качестве параметра выступает название поля объекта

Tags: javascript, функции, typescript, шаблоны, typescript-типы

у меня есть множество однотипных функций для сортировки, которые передаются фреймворку, отрисовывающему таблицы и сортирующему поля (Ant Desgin) и отличающуюся названием полей и типом данных:

```
sorter: (a: IType1, b: IType1) => (a.created_at ?? 0) - (b.created_at ?? 0),
```

хочется вместо кода сравнения двух значений указывать какую-то более короткую запись, не зависящую от типа данных, что-то типа

```
sorter: my_sorter,
```

Если написать функцию

```
function my_sorter(a: IType1, b: IType1) {
    return (a.created_at ?? 0) - (b.created_at ?? 0);
}
```

То это то, что надо за исключением 2х вещей - одна применима только для заданного типа и заданного названия поля, а хотелось бы указывать функцию и дополнительно указывать поля и типы данных (если нужно), что-то типа

```
sorter: my_sorter<IType1.created_at>,
```

Можно ли это реализовать в typescript?

P.S.

Не очень бы хотелось указывать поля в виде строк и т.д., т.е. легко можно написать функцию, чтобы делать так:

```
sorter: (a: IType1, b: IType1) => my_sorter(a, b, 'created_at'),
```

Но это уже как-то менее эстетично :(

Comment: А как JS в рантайме должен узнать поле? Типов TS для JS движка не существует.

Comment: ну я в шаблоне в явном виде указываю же поле, поэтому и интересует, можно ли без использования строки или нет, типа в шаблоне указываю воспринимай полученные данные как `Type1` и извлеки из него поле `create_at`

Comment: Я думаю нельзя.

Comment: Так я не понимаю что же будет написано в теле функции?

Comment: Может такое?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgQwE4FMBCAngMJ6ZS4AmAglADwAqiuAHhWJQM6IDeyZFSgH1yAfgBciMCFQAjXNkQBfAHwAKTJIYAaRLK0BKXgChEZxHighsSDQDoIAqiKiJRoxAAYjAWkRrZBydhcjcPbwBuYyVjY0pcCAAbHFxkZM5uAFVOBRNzKUxUXElOKGwYMABzKPzHXHJncklpOQUomLiE5Lw0zAzEYhw881Q4eMSSsorq03M6hpCoCSkZeWx22PiklN7+gGUAC0x0VJ5ZsyhCE8nyqo3O7Z7E3FcQHOxOSWyFAG0AXSiW26qWerggOE+Axw-0BXR2oMQnCOJ0hh2OuBhsQA9FjEIBBEEAfCCAARBAEIggA4QIkEwBMIIAuEEADCCIQD8IASmQTANwggDkQfj1QQuOzGN4KTh2ThwbBQNQoDApIikHlUWgGKLgj4isUSqVYPCy4KKqI4xAAASgnB8rBO0DN2GwYsQgF4QQCsICTWWzAPIg3IWfOMSPRwtF4slaC1BBIuqgSqAA

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации функции сортировки которая будет принимать ключ и возвращать отсортированный массив можно воспользоваться типом который отсечёт все лишние ключи не содержащие число и сделать функцию с замыканием которая будет принимать тот самый ключ и возвращать результат для функции `sort`

**Рабочий пример**: [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMDSEQGcA8AKgHxQC8UA3gFBRQDamUqAdlANY4D2AZlIQF0AXP0YCoEAB7AILACa4oLRACMUUAPxQmIlhABuKANzUAvvU4he-ASeo84LdMFRc26LgjABDZBABCINggUEQS0rIKUFwqAFYQzqQAFJYi8EhoWDiKRKQANFDocLjAngBq3gA2qHLeLm4aIkneuqooBSqtCGrIAJTkpMrdKP00dH7AcMhszSKEHXP9ZKRjdMx8SUUl5VU1da4so7Rr4xCT04XFpQgV1bX1LEnpPc0WOAK9Bc8oSSpvIB9eiYTqYJJVcNBVicJlM2N9kK9LB8oABaWBtBF-JFA450UzHUwmfHUAD0JOo1FYMmQPG86GgAFUIcgqMcWN4kCISmgWABzYGFPx1CByAD6dS6PSJFKpKFp9KgAGFfKy6DVJcZjgguHIIJUucAefyzBSPCwSlBiihcCImSh6OIKPRjpQlByICIAOQyC0ARk9BXQQpkYolUF9UFMeRdbs5UG9EAtACYA4KIMLQ8AREnI9G6K72XGExaAMypoPpkPirNQEu56i2CnUM0W9C%20G1K3wO8gMGPq8MFbW6-Xxn3AcOe%20v55hybODnV6r1jqApqdUGciEvz4dLxPjsv1xvUK3IXAAOlwXGQwE2nh8fkCwXwduQxCSnorGernt6QKgZIYX0CiTAoSwEY9mXPS9r1vLxfACIIcGfZk3w-YMRW-Apmg6JZkhUVEoG8X8-wA%20gtxXApfXA5t2wvK8bw8OCH0QkB8GVV93xqH8SJJQDgNA8C21POiYMY%208EKfdjUK4rDvBwgYoF%20AiiN-Ix-14sj%20PDAQgA)

```
type NumericKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends number ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

function compareByKey<T extends object>(key: NumericKeys<T>, customValidation?: (a: number, b: number) => number) {
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    if (customValidation) {
      return customValidation(Number(a[key]), Number(b[key]));
    } else {
      return Number(a[key]) - Number(b[key]);
    }
  };
}

//

interface User {
  name: string;
  created_at: number;
}

interface Car {
  id: number;
  model: string;
}

const users: User[] = [
  { name: 'test 1', created_at: 1 },
  { name: 'test 2', created_at: 2 },
  { name: 'test 3', created_at: 3 },
];


const cars: Car[] = [
  { id: 1, model: 'test 1' },
  { id: 2, model: 'test 2' },
  { id: 3, model: 'test 3' },
];

users.sort(compareByKey<User>('created_at')); // [1, 2, 3]
users.sort(compareByKey<User>('created_at', (a, b) => (b - a))); // [3, 2, 1]

cars.sort(compareByKey<Car>('id')); // [1, 2, 3]
cars.sort(compareByKey<Car>('id', (a, b) => (b - a))); // [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: А вообще, создавать велосипед необязательно, готовые типизированные функции описаны в библиотеке [lodash](https://lodash.com/), [пример sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy).